# How to click a JButton multiple times, changing the button text each time?

Tags: java

I can't find a solution for this that works for more than 2 clicks. I want to use an actionlistener on my button, so that on each click, the button text changes between "A", "B" and "C" in this order.

My "click" is set to 0 right now as I don't know what to set it to in order to do this.

```
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            button = (JButton) event.getSource()
            click = 0;
            switch (click) {
                case 0:
                    button.setText("A");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    button.setText("B");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    button.setText("C");
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close. What should work is moving the `click` out of the method:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    int click = 0;
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        button = (JButton) event.getSource()
        switch (click % 3) { // loop back around after 3 clicks
            case 0:
                button.setText("A");
                break;
            case 1:
                button.setText("B");
                break;
            case 2:
                button.setText("C");
                break;
        }
        click++;
    }
});
```